# How to get a layout size before it's displayed?

Tags: android, view

I inflate a layout containing an `ImageView` and a `RelativeLayout`. The layout has its width set to `match_parent` and its height set to `wrap_content`. The height is determined by the `ImageView`, but the image set to the `ImageView` is loaded dynamically from the internet.

Since I know the image ratio, I'd like to set the size of the `ImageView` before it's displayed to avoid a jump in the UI due to the change in the layout height when the image is set.

To set the size I need the layout width, to compute the `ImageView` height.

I tried

```
int width = header.getMeasuredWidth();
```

but since the layout is not drawn yet it returns 0

I also tried to use `measure` before, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5383811/326849)

```
header.measure(0, 0);
int width = header.getMeasuredWidth();
```

but `measure` returns a `NullPointerException`

How can I do that?

**list_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_text_container"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#789987">
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyListFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

    View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);

    int width = header.getMeasuredWidth(); // 0 because not drawn yet

    ImageView pic = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.pic);
    pic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, (int) (width/imgRatio)));

    pic.invalidate();
    header.invalidate();

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Simply you can not. You can try to override onMeasure from ViewGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with a ViewTreeObserver.
Your Fragment/Activity should implement OnGlobalLayoutListener, in OnActivityCreate declare handler

```
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.header_text_container)
ViewTreeObserver vto = container.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
```

and put your width logic in listener when size are available

```
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Remember to remove handler
    container.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);

            int width = header.getMeasuredWidth(); // 0 because not drawn yet
            ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the size in Activity's **onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)** method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width and height of a view in onGlobalLayout, wich is a method to Callback method wich is invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes (thus as soon as the view is drawn and the size is known).

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = header.getViewTreeObserver();

if(vto!=null){
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            header.getWidth();
            header.getHeight();
        }
    });
}
```