# Get parent Width and Height

Tags: android, layout

I've create a custom view based on `LinearLayout` and I need to calculate the layout width and height according to the parent view but each time I use `((View)this.getParent()).getMeasuredWidth()` I got `0` -  I guess that I called this function too early!

Any ideas to how accomplish this functionality?

Comment: what error you are getting please post log cat

Comment: @Hardik I don't get any errors, I just get zero value instead of actual layout width and height!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375631/get-view-width-height-or-font-width-height-other-sizes-before-first-display

Comment: try my answer and tell me

Comment: Are you doing this in onCreate()?

Comment: parent view "tells you it's size". you can get in from measureSpecs which passed by parent to child measure method.

Comment: @Simon Yes, I called this function in `onCreate()`

Comment: The UI is not measured and drawn until after onCreate().  Hardik has the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

in **Kotlin** you can use like this :

```
   val height = (parent as View).height
```

Answer (score -1):

if your view parent have layout params `"android:layout_width="wrapContent"`, you can not get the width.